# N/A instead of #DIV/0! in calculated column

Tags: calculated-column

I have a calculated column with the calculation =(TotalHoursWorked/PlannedHours)*100&" %"

If the column plannedHours is empty, I get the error #DIV/0!. Instead I want it to be showing N/A.

I have tried the following sting but it doesn't work. Have I missed something or do you have any suggestions on solution?

=IF(ISERROR(TotalHoursWorked/PlannedHours),"N/A",((TotalHoursWorked/PlannedHours)*100&" %")

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a final ) to close off the IF statement.